# How do I concatenate a list of pandas dataframes using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, aggregate

- I have a function `functionA` that takes a file path and outputs a
  dataframe `dfA`
- I have a list `listAll` that contains all file paths
- I'm trying to create a function `functionB` that takes in `listAll` and outputs 1
  single dataframe `dfB` that is an aggregation of `dfA` for all file
  paths

**Problem:** I can't figure out the aggregation part, everything I try ends up creating a `dfB` that is 1 dataframe but only contains the `dfA` of the last file path repeated (length based on `listAll`)

**Have tried:**

```
def functionB(listAll):
  for i in range(len(listAll)):
    Tables = functionA(listAll[i])

  return Tables

Table1 = [functionB(listAll) for x in listAll]

dfB = pd.concat(Table1)
```

---

```
def functionB(listAll):
    Tables = pd.DataFrame()

    for i in range(len(listAll)):
      Tables = pd.concat([functionA(listAll[i])]),axis=0,ignore_index=True)

    return Tables
    
Table1 = [functionB(listAll) for x in listAll]
        
dfB = pd.concat(Table1)
```

Comment: You don't need to define any extra functions. You can just do with a generator expression `pd.concat(pd.read_csv(i) for i in listAll, axis=0, ignore_index=True)`.

Comment: Where does `functionA` go?

Comment: FunctionA can go in place of `read_csv()`.

Comment: I tried `pd.concat(functionA(i) for i in listAll, axis=0, ignore_index=True)` and received `SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized`

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. There should be an extra set of parentheses: `pd.concat((functionA(i) for i in listAll), axis=0, ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 0):

In both your trials the Tables variable gets overwritten!

Try (I pythonized ;) ):

```
def combine_dataframes(path_list: list[str]):
    tables = pd.DataFrame()

    for path in path_list:
        # feel free to add axis/ignore_index:
        tables.concat(functionA(path))  

    return tables

uberframe = combine_dataframes(listAll)
```

`concat` can also take a list of other dataframes. I guess this should work, too:

```
def dataframe_from_paths(all_paths):
    tables = pd.DataFrame()
    return tables.concat([functionA(path) for path in all_paths])
```

And finally using reduce:

```
from functools import reduce


def dataframe_from_paths(all_paths):
    def concat_dataframes(a, b):
        return a.concat(functionA(b))

    return reduce(concat_dataframes, all_paths, pd.DataFrame())
```

`reduce` takes a function, an iterable and optionally a starting element.

The function contains the magic. It takes 2 arguments and the first one is the last element and the second one is the current element.

Comment: I tried this but a `TypeError` comes up in the `def` line:

`----> 3 def combine_dataframes(path_list: list[str]):`

`TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I tried using the updated functions you posted but am now getting `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'` when I run `dataframe_from_paths(listAll)`